# Android Text Display for Beginner

Tags: android, textview

This is a very basic question, I know, but I cannot seem to figure it out on my own.  While the Android tutorial will help you make a practice app, it does not really tell you what you are doing.  (I have already successfully completed their tutorial.)  All of my searches have come up with less newbish questions without answering my question.  So here is my beginner's question:

I want to display the text "Sup World."  What am I doing wrong?  I am sure the null is wrong, but I cannot figure out what should actually be there. "this" does not work.  And with null in there, setContextView does not exist.

```
package com.evorlor.testcode;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class SupWorld {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String message = "Sup world.";

        TextView textView = new TextView(null);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(textView);

    }

}
```

My issue is not in getting to my SupWorld class, is it?:

```
package com.evorlor.testcode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SupWorld.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: "While the Android tutorial will help you make a practice app, it does not really tell you what you are doing" -- when you compared your code to the results of any of those tutorials, such as [Building Your First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) to see what was different in your code versus the tutorial's, what did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Code as:

```
public class SupWorld extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         String message = "Sup world.";

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(textView);

    }

}
```

Declares above  activity class in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SupWorld" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

apart this you will to look some good tutorials for Creating your first application in android see these

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: Thanks.  It will now compile, but it is says "Unforunately, Text Code has stopped." in the emulator.  It never displays "Sup world."

Comment: @SamuelKnox : post your full log and your latest code also for more help

Comment: My manifest was made by eclipse, so I doubt the problem is there.  I made the SupWorld class directly from my MainActivity.  I have posted the MainActivity code above.

Comment: @SamuelKnox : what you want ? you want to start SupWorld activity from MainActivity activity?

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed my problem with displaying text.  It seemed I had two issues...the one you fixed, and the SupWorld class is not being called.  (I changed it in the manifest, and it ran...so now I just need to figure this out.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First answer **SEARCH THIS SIMPLE QUESTION**

Second answer :

```
   public class SupWorld extends Activity {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public void onCreate(Bundle l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(l);

        String message = "Sup world.";

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        setContentView(textView);

    }

  }
```

Add this activity to menifest and run

Answer (score 0):

Instead of being given the answer, I think its best to explain why its failing. Basically this line is your culprit:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(null);
```

When looking at the constructor of a TextView, you'll see that it requires Context. Context is used in android for Attaching content the the respective application. In this case, Context is required for using the TextView as this TextView belongs to this application.

The correct way is passing context:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

Or

```
TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

Once you attach the respective Context, then it will work. null is not a valid context, and will throw a null pointer exception (NPE).

Try reading the documentation on [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to learn more.

### Also

the Other error that could have been caused is the Activity is not registered in your AndroidManifest.xml as `ρяσѕρєя K` pointed out. This is required so that the application knows to register that Activity underneath the Application you are trying to register it under.